# Where is the documentation for OpenSMPP?

Tags: java, mobile, sms, smpp

[the OpenSMPP homepage](http://www.opensmpp.org) does not contain the documentation of OpenSMPP itself, only the protocol references. Could somebody give me some advice where on Earth can I find documentation and code examples on how to use the OpenSMPP API itself, especially regarding what classes can be used for receiving asynchronously?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the API (Javadoc)
 - this will be resolved by your IDE if you include the library in your project follwing the instructions here `http://opensmpp.org/downloads.html`
 - if you want to download the API manually start to have a look here `https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/opensmpp/`

For examples you could have a look in the unit tests, clone (or download) the project `https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp.git` and have a look for sources in the 'client/', 'sim/' or '*/test/' folders.

For testing purpose this tutorial might be also of interest: `http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sending-sms-with-smpp-kannel-and-java`